# Is possible to backup jenkins AD through thin backup plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is possible to backup Jenkins AD through thin backup plugins? I cannot able to restore Jenkins AD through plugins. I was try to backup Jenkins AD through plugins. Is any other option to backup AD through  periodical backup?